# Display description before the title in WooCommerce product category archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

In WooCommerce, I am trying to display the description before the title in Product category archive pages. But I fail trying to find out what hooks could I use to do it.

The idea was to have a "Flavour Menu" be displayed first, and then the title afterwards, like in this screenshot:

[image]

Any track is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to override the template `templates/archive-product.php` located in the Woocommerce plugin, copying it to your active theme folder to a `woocommerce` subfolder `(but not in a`templates`subfolder)`.

Read this official related documentation: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Once done, open / edit it and replace:

```
?>
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
</header>
<?php
```

with the following *(we are adding a custom hook before the title)*:

```
?>
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
    <?php 
    /**
     * Custom Hook: woocommerce_custom_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_custom_archive_description' ); ?>

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
</header>
<?php
```

Then save…

Now you will add the following in the function.php file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*, where we will unhook the product category description from the default hook, to hook it in our new custom hook *(before the title)*:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_custom_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
```

Save, you are done… Tested and works.